# Is it acceptable that the Skip Main Navigation link focuses on a page's main content and then ignores what is in the footer?

Tags: accessibility, nvda

While testing one of my websites with NVDA, I realized that when I click the Skip Main Navigation link NVDA only reads what is inside the main container that the link points to. Since the Footer comes after it, NVDA does not read any of the content in it. With additional links located in the Footer as well as some important Policy links, I was wondering if this causes any sort of issues for screen reader users. I know that they can continue to navigate using Headings, tabbing and using arrow keys but I'm wondering if anyone knows if this causes a bad user experience for them and if anyone has any recommendations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue with this behavior.

The section of WCAG 2.1 that deals with this topic is [Success Criteria 2.4.1, Bypass Blocks](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/bypass-blocks).

The purpose of "skip links" or "[bypass blocks](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG21/#bypass-blocks)" is:

```
to bypass blocks of content that are repeated on multiple Web pages
```

Footer content would qualify as content that is repeated on each page.

Comment: Thanks for the reference. It makes me feel a little better reading that.

Answer (score 0):

No this is not an issue. They would use navigation keys (read next) in any screen reader.

In NVDA this would be the NVDA key and the down arrow normally.

This is expected behaviour. (assuming your page uses the correct markup and doesn't have problems, without seeing the page it is impossible to tell).

One suggestion is to use more than one skip link to allow people to access the footer directly (especially if it contains important information). You can do this by simply including multiple skip links and having them appear on focus.

### Example

A quick example of multiple skip links. You may have to press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> to get to the skip links depending on where you click in the window.

```css
.skiplink {
    padding:6px;
    position: absolute;
    top:-40px;
    left:0px;
    color:#000000;
    border-right:1px solid white;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    border-bottom-right-radius:8px;
    background:transparent;
    -webkit-transition: top 1s ease-out, background 1s linear;
    transition: top 1s ease-out, background 1s linear;
    z-index: 100
}
.skiplink:focus {
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    background:#F1B82D;
    outline:0;
    -webkit-transition: top .1s ease-in, background .5s linear;
    transition: top .1s ease-in, background .5s linear
}
nav{
   padding-bottom: 50px;
}
main{
margin-top: 200px;
}
li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    background-color:#000;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
li a {
    color:#fff;   
}

li a:hover, li a:focus {
    color:#ccc;   
}

#mainContent {
    clear:both;   
}

h2 {
    margin-top:15px;            
}

footer{
  margin-bottom: 300px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#mainContent" class="skiplink">Skip to Main Content</a>
<a href="#footer" class="skiplink">Skip to Footer</a>
<nav>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">First</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Second</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Third</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Fourth</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Fifth</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sixth</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Seventh</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Eighth</a>
    </li>
</ul></nav>
<main id="mainContent">
<h1>Main Content</h1>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jf
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
<p> 
fjdsk jflk;dsj lk;gfdjlk; fjds;lk jgdlfk;hg kljdsah foiwjrvoienmiu pjgoidfj foipje fgds;lk jlk;fdgajlk;f jsl;kgj s;lka jgl;kdfasj glk;dsa jl;k fjdsal;ka 
</p>
</main>
<footer id="footer">
 SKIPPED TO FOOTER
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using Header, Nav, Main and Footer elements. I'm just new to NVDA testing. I want to avoid using more than one "skip" link at this time.