# Screenreaders 'skip to main content' function in angularjs

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility

As the title states, I'm in need of a function that has the same result as the below bootstrap snippet. The show on focus part works perfectly fine, but on clicking the button the scroll to 'main content' doesn't work in angularjs.

```
 <body>
      <a href="#content" class="sr-only sr-only-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
      ...
      <div class="container" id="content" tabindex="-1">
        <!-- The main page content -->
      </div>
 </body>
```

I understand what is needed in theory, but I'm new to angularjs and I'm not entirely sure how to approach this.

1. The 'show main content' button will initially be set to `position: absolute; left: -9999;` to hide from view.
2. on keyboard focus the button will then be set to `position: static` which will show the button on the page.
3. On click the user will be taken to the 'main content' section of the page using something like  $anchorScroll(); which I found here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$anchorScroll

I suppose my real issue here, is combining the two functions on focus do this on click do that.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62760090/2702894 shows how to do the CSS side of things. You don't actually need to use angular as a `#main` linked to a corresponding anchor `<div id="main">` will scroll the page automatically. The example I linked allows for several skip links. Click into the example and press tab, the skip links will appear. If you only need one then just remove the second skip link. You also don't need `tabindex="-1"` if you do this.

Comment: @GrahamRitchie Thanks for the response. However, the hashtag is added to the end of the URL and the page is reloaded in angularjs. The css part works perfectly though, it's just the scroll to which is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround for this. It turns out because the anchor tag is expecting a href it was messing with the focus. After changing the a tag to a button element, it worked fine.